# Formula to assign queue based on regional business unit

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

Excuse my lack of experience on formula's....I am trying to create a formula in a flow variable to assign a queue name to a lead based on what RBU (regional business unit) value is for that lead.  I have it working if I just put in a static hardcoded string in that variable, but I would like to make that variable "smarter" to look for the RBU and use the hardcoded queue id based on the RBU value.  Here is what I have so far, but I cannot seem to get it working properly:

```
AND(            
        OR (
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "Asia Pacific", '<id for queue to assign to>'), 
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "Canada", '<id for queue to assign to>'), 
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "Europe", '<id for queue to assign to>'),
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "Central America", '<id for queue to assign to>'),
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "South America", '<id for queue to assign to>'),
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "United States", '<id for queue to assign to>'),
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "Middle East", '<id for queue to assign to>'), 
ISPICKVAL(RBU__c), "",'<id for queue to assign to>'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hardcoding ids is not a good idea. At least use developer name of the queue and query id for the queue in the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your formula doesn't check next values. So Why you're not using `case` for this things as like below,

```
Case (TEXT(RBU__c),

"Asia Pacific", '<id for queue to assign to>',
"Canada", '<id for queue to assign to>',
"Europe", '<id for queue to assign to>',
"Central America", '<id for queue to assign to>',
"South America", '<id for queue to assign to>',
"United States", '<id for queue to assign to>',
"Middle East", '<id for queue to assign to>',
'<id for queue to assign to>' //Default
)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: MohanRaj, I am getting the following error:

NewVariable (Formula) - The formula expression is invalid: Field RBU__c does not exist. Check spelling.

However, that field does exist in the Lead object.

Comment: Field name "Regional_Business_Unit_Global" is wrong. Please check whether it's custom field means, it's should be ended with "__c".

Comment: I did, it's RBU__c but same error.

Comment: Then please check, whether the RBU__c field is in same object which you used in flow. Otherwise, it's need to indicate with parent like "X__r.RBU__c".

Comment: Yeah, I tried Lead__r.RBU__c and same error.  This is odd, it's as if it doesn't see the field at all even when using it's API name.